# jquery show list of words using fade

Tags: jquery

I am brand new to jquery but im hoping someone points me in right direction with this simple question, what's the best way to show a list of words 1 after another in my **div** ? for example in this simple code

```
<div id="Mylist"> </div>
```

I would like to show 3 words One after another which are the continents North America,Europe,Asia so it would go like this

North America (show for 2 seconds, then move to the next one)

Europe (show for 2 seconds, then move to the next one)

Asia (show for 2 seconds, then start with North America again)

Comment: Showing lists in HTML is usually done with list elements, shortened to `<li>`, within an ordered list (`<ol>`) or an unordered list (`<ul>`) ? Why not start there ?

Comment: Because I wanted to make the list Dynamic only showing 1 element at a time and changing every 2 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use delayed animation. For example with a setup like this:

```
<div id="Mylist" > 
    <span>North America</span>
    <span>Europe</span>
    <span>Asia</span>
</div>

#Mylist span {
    display:none
}
```

You can use code:

```
$("#Mylist span").each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(i*2000).fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(1000)
})
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DZ2uE/1/

Note: This code both shows and hides words, feel free to adjust animation as needed. E.g this one http://jsfiddle.net/DZ2uE/2/ just shows.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

```
<div id="mylist">
    <span>North America</span>
    <span>Europe </span>
    <span>Asia</span>
</div>
```

You can try:

```
function animate(el){


    el.fadeIn(function(){
        if(typeof el !== 'undefined') animate(el.next()); continue recursion only if there's a next sibling element
    });
}

animate($('#mylist').children(':first'));
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JuCSX/)

Answer (score 0):

This is not much of the jquery related question but its a general JavaScript logic question

You need to store words in some array and use setInterval for 2 seconds interval. at each interval you just need to maintain proper index of the array.

[CodeBins Rotating Word](http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp42/2/Rotating%20Words)

```
$(function() {
    var words = ["North America", "Europe", "Asia"];
    var totalWords = words.length;
    var currentWord = 0;
    var $myList = $("#Mylist")
    var showWord = function() {
            $myList.html(words[currentWord]);
            currentWord = (currentWord + 1) % totalWords;
        }
    setInterval(showWord, 2000);
    showWord();

})
```