# Disallow one animation to begin until the other one ends

Tags: jquery

What I'm basically trying to do is get the background of my whole website to go black, scroll down to a specific point and then go back to normal which works FINE but it executes all three animations at the same time, I was wondering if there was a way to prevent this? My jQuery is this

```
$('.gotohtml5andcss3').click(function () {

    $('#bg_black').fadeIn('fast');

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".html5andcss3").offset().top
    }, 1000);

    $('#bg_black').fadeOut('fast');
});
```

I'm not asking for the code, just a nudge in the right direction.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use delays. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19034364/jquery-show-list-of-words-using-fade/19034580#19034580

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use callback function like

```
$('#bg_black').fadeIn('fast', function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".html5andcss3").offset().top
    }, 1000);
});
```

Complete Code:

```
$('.gotohtml5andcss3').click(function () {
    $('#bg_black').fadeIn('fast', function(){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(".html5andcss3").offset().top
        }, 1000, function(){
            $('#bg_black').fadeOut('fast');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Note that the `animate` callback will happen for **each** element being animated, so for instance the `$('html body').animate(...)` callback will fire twice.

Comment: Thank you! and @T.J.Crowder thanks for the info on the callback firing twice, will change it to what I need

Answer (score 2):

You can chain the animations into each other's callback functions.  Something like this:

```
$('#bg_black').fadeIn('fast', function () {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".html5andcss3").offset().top
    }, 1000, function () {
        $('#bg_black').fadeOut('fast');
    });
});
```

Since each one happens asynchronously, you'd want to use its call-back function parameter to execute the next step in a serial sequence of steps.

Comment: Note that the `animate` callback will happen for **each** element being animated, so for instance the `$('html body').animate(...)` callback will fire twice.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Good point.  The OP will definitely want to tweak to meet his needs.